# Can neo4j queries return implicit relationships?

Tags: neo4j

I'm evaluating Neo4j and a quick google doesn't answer this question for me (or i'm just up too late)...

Can neo4j queries return implicit relationships?  For example:

Using the movie DB in sandbox, can I generate a graph of actors who've acted alongside other actors?

Instead of a graph of movie nodes linked to person nodes, I want a graph of only person nodes "linked" to other person nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using virtual nodes and relationships, you can do this. See https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/virtual/